# Converting XMLDocument object to String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I want to convert XMLDocument object that I'm getting as a response from an ajax request, to a string. I tried using

```
new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlObject)
```

and I get the following response:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ns2:errorList xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/api/delivery/V1"><error code="DOMAIN_VALIDATE" path="delivery.shipper"><message>empty</message></error><error code="DOMAIN_VALIDATE" path="delivery.shipperSite"><message>empty</message></error><error code="DOMAIN_VALIDATE" path="delivery.leg"><message>invalid</message></error></ns2:errorList>
```

Means the method converted the whole XMLDocument into string, including the very first tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

I don't want this part of the response. Is there any method that does that.
Note: I don't want to use the workarounds like "substr" etc.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can do this by serializing just the root node:

```
new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlObject.documentElement);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/LmWkL/

Comment: There should be a 'save this answer somewhere because you're going to search for it another million times' button in SO...

Comment: @Nathan you can click on "Bookmark this question" and in your profile you will find those under "Bookmarks".

Comment: @Patric, nearly six years later it turned out that I didn't search for anything XML-related quite as much... But thanks for the tip, I didn't know about that!

Comment: Why not just `xmlObject.documentElement.outerHTML`?

Comment: @AaronJ: AFAICT, there's no reason not to use that now, given that it is standardized and works on XML. Historically, `outerHTML` was non-standard for years while `XMLSerializer` existed. I'm having a hard time finding out whether it was standardized by 2013, and if so, whether it could be relied upon for XML documents as well as HTML. Personally, I'd probably still use `XMLSerializer` because the name is more suggestive of its purpose than `outerHTML`; `outerHTML` would catch my eye as being potentially wrong in XML-related code and I'd have to look it up, which makes it less readable.